# Creating paths from external location and rotation data

Tags: path

I have a program that calculates the trajectory of an object based on different parameters, the output is a matrix with the time the object reaches the point, X,Y and Z coordinates of the point and 3 degrees for rotation/orientation on each point.
Can I import that data in blender and make a path with that data? I can change the output of the first program to whatever format is needed.

**EDIT:**

As requested I will try to give more details. In this days I found how to create a curve that an object can follow like this:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

coords_list = [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [-3,2,1], [0,0,-4]]
# make a new curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# make a new spline in that curve
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')

# a spline point for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords_list)-1) # theres already one point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)

# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

It creates a curve using the coordinates from coords_list.

What I need now is to add rotation to the object in each point. I have 3 angles defining how much rotation there is in each plane (X,Y,Z) respect the origin and each of the points from the original matrix have a set of rotation angles. It would be something like this:

```
[Timestamp, X, Y, Z, rotX, rotY, rotZ]
```

In the example above I would apply just X, Y and Z, next step would be adding rotX, rotY and rotZ so that the object rotates along the path.

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GboXB9G8xQ&t=370s), I want to do what he does there but with a script, is it possible? and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you give any more details? Otherwise the answer is yes, you can import the data with a Python script and create geometry from it.

Comment: @Blunder I have added more details, is it enough?

Comment: So you have a Nurbs curve? Problem here is that the control points are not on the curve. But when you have X,Y,Z that are on the curve and rotation values you can assign them to the object. Should be a simple transformation then. The object's location is in object.location and rotation is in object.rotation[0..2] with *pi* (3.14159...) = 180°